# how do I make an element not work as href in an entire href card

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

[image]

So I have this card that works as an entire link but inside that, I have an icon under a span tag and I don't want it to work as the card's link rather just act like an icon, Ik I can solve this if I don't make the entire card href but then I'd have to manually turn all the required elements present inside the card into href which I feel like isn't efficient and neat. So any suggestions on how do I go from here?

```
.card {
  width: 250px;
  height: 350;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.top {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

}

.year {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  font-family: Circular Std Book;

}

.span-bookmark {
  padding-left: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;

}



{% for m in mlist %}
    <div class="card">
        <a href="http://www.google.com/search?q={{m.Name}}" target="_blank">
            <div class="top">
                <div class="year">{{m.Year}}</div>
                <span class="span-bookmark"><i class="material-icons bookmark" id="bookmark-style">bookmark</i></span>
            </div>

            <div class="middle">
                <div class="img-container"><img src="{{ m.Image.url }}"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="bottom">
                <div class="title">{{m.Name}}</div>
                <div class="target_id">{{m.targetid}}</div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a position set on both the card and the icon div. Then set a z-index for the icon that is higher than the card in your css. Then if you assign the icon to be clickable, it won't click the card link when you click the icon. You can use z-index to arrange all the layers in your card.

Comment: That's a pretty gd idea but IDK why isn't it working @bjastski

Comment: could you provide some of your css related to this whole card so I can recreate and possibly find the issue?

Comment: Sure thing, just a one moment

Comment: Hey Zeniel, after looking closer, I think you have to remove it from the 'a' tag. If you put it outside the 'a' tag but still inside your card div, you can give the card it's relative position, then give the bookmark span an absolute position, then give the bookmark something like 'right: 10px, top:0px" in your css, that along with the z-index will make sure it doesn't click the card link while keeping it on the card.

Comment: it's better to go with js I felt like to handle this situation but your idea isn't bad either so Imma give you an upvote and thnx for helping

Comment: Sounds good, I'm glad you found a solution that worked for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can stop navigation with *preventDefault* and stop bubbling up to the link with *stopPropagation*.

In the following demo, clicking on the img doesn't bubble up the DOM. Clicking on the div outside the img bubbles up to the A, as does clicking on the A text.

```js
function showStuff(event) {
  // Stop default action, e.g. following a link
  event.preventDefault();
  // Stop click from bubbling, e.g. to link parent
  event.stopPropagation();
  // Just for demonstration purposes, delete when no longer required
  console.log('Click from ' + event.target.tagName +
    ' reached ' + event.currentTarget.tagName);
}

window.onload = function() {

  // This listener is for demo only and prevents following the link
  // Don't add it if you want to follow the link for clicks outside the img
  let link = document.querySelector('a');
  link.addEventListener('click', showStuff, false);

  // This listener stops clicks from the img reaching the A and
  // stops navigation from clicks on the img
  let img = document.querySelector('img');
  img.addEventListener('click', showStuff, false);
}
```

```css
.card {
  width: 250px;
  height: 350;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-color: white;
  margin: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.middle {
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

img {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <a href="http://www.google.com/search?q={{m.Name}}" target="_blank">Some link text
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="img-container"><img src="foo.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    Some more link text
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: it's not working for all the cards in the db don't know why

Comment: Updated example to be more like the OP.

Comment: Define "not working". A click on the image does not bubble to the A element. A click on the link is also blocked for the sake of the demonstration, so remove that listener if you want to follow the link.

Comment: I have a lot of cards and it works only for one, and I used the concept for the span and what happened was, the link stopped(as required) but the icon didn't work either but again it was just working for the 1st card